# An event with multiple senders

Tags: events, design-patterns, event-handling, c++builder

How to create an event of clicking on **ANY** of four buttons, i.e. avoid pasting same code into each button's OnClick event? The only thing I found in Google is that there is (?) a [pattern](http://www.marco.panizza.name/dispenseTM/slides/exerc/eventNotifier/eventNotifier.html) (Multicast) for it. If it really exists, could you please provide me some examples, if not, could you make (a draft of) one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the same handler to all four button `OnClick` events.  The event's `Sender` parameter will tell you which button is triggering the event each time.  For example:

```
void __fastcall TMyForm::ButtonClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    TButton *btn = static_cast<TButton*>(Sender);
    ShowMessage("You clicked on " + btn->Name);
}
```

If your code needs to behave depending on which button is clicked, you can use the `Tag` property to differentiate, for example:

```
void __fastcall TMyForm::ButtonClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    TButton *btn = static_cast<TButton*>(Sender);
    switch (btn->Tag)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Why to differentiate between the buttons using the Tag property, instead of just comparing the static_casted Sender to the pointer to a specific TButton?

Comment: @SamuliHynönen: you can certainly do that as well, but it requires separate `if` statements for each button. Using the `Tag`, you can do things like using `switch` statements, indexing arrays, etc. It really depends on what the event handler's code is actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the Button1->OnClick have been assigned :

```
Button2->OnClick = Button1->OnClick
Button3->OnClick = Button1->OnClick
Button4->OnClick = Button1->OnClick
```